# Unavailable projects in vs 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Where does the *indication* of *unavailable or available* (loaded) projects / websites  is saved?

I have a solution which has some unloaded projects while *only* the website is loaded

Of course I can right click and *reload it* but *still*, I want to now *where* this [unavailable or available] info is saved?

[image]

I've been looking in the `sln`, there is no difference (beyond compare) between loaded one and unloaded one.

Also in `Websites.xml`, there is no such difference

Comment: I believe it's in the .suo file

Comment: @SteveB this is what i also thought .....bnut it is a binary file. can i delete it ? will vs will recreate it ?

Comment: The suo file stands for "solution user object" (it's a guess). It's a per-user container of solution settings. You can safely delete it, but you will loose some other non important things, like breakpoints, and so on. In most VCS, this file is in the standard exclusion list, as it should remain specific for each user.

Comment: It will certainly recreate it, but I'm not sure how much information is there. Certainly the code won't stop compiling.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The suo file stands for "solution user object" (it's a guess).

It's a per-user container of solution settings.

You can safely delete it, but you will lose some other non important things, like breakpoints, and so on.

In most VCS, this file is in the standard exclusion list, as it should remain specific for each user. This is the evidence you can safely delete it.

Comment: You rock man ! I deleted the file , it did recreate it ( after 5 min of "get latest from source control" and then it reseted all the avilable/unavailable thing. now i can disable/enable projects. thanks :-)

Comment: I was suspicious about that strange file.  I even got to a point where i thought it keeps it in registery(after negate the *.sln and websitecache.xml)

Comment: I had the same exact problem and deleting the *.sou file fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the information regarding loaded and unavailable projects in a solution is stored in the .suo file. As mentioned previously, this is a user-specific, binary settings file auto-generated and maintained by Visual Studio.

It's worth pointing out that some projects won't load if the machine doesn't have the relevant software installed (e.g. an [MVC web application project](http://www.asp.net/mvc) won't load on a machine that does not have it installed; similarly for [WIX projects](http://wix.sourceforge.net/)).

If you have intentionally unloaded projects to improve the overall load time of your solution, then you should know that [Visual Studio 2012 now supports asynchronous loading of projects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb386063%28v=vs.110%29#BKMK_IDEProjects).

You might also have a look at spinning some projects out into other solutions, grouping by major system features (be wary of breaking project dependencies.)